# Can't insert query result into table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert some information to a new table in my database. For this I query information from two tables and a xref table, then I try to do the insert as I usually do. This is not working.
Here is the code,

```
$query = "select listaA.product_s_desc, category_name, listaA.product_desc, listaA.product_sku 
from listaA, jos_vm_category, jos_vm_product_category_xref 
where listaA.product_id = jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_id 
and  jos_vm_category.category_id = jos_vm_product_category_xref.category_id limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die;
do{
        $imagen = 'http://accesoriosazteca.mx/imagesite/'.$row['listaA.product_sku'].".png";
        mysql_query("insert into lista_importat (id, activo, sku, nombre, categoria, descripcion_corta, descripcion_larga, pedidos, mostrar_precio, imagen) 
        values ('$row['listaA.product_id']', '1', '$row['listaA.product_sku']', '$row['listaA.product_s_desc']', '', '$row['listaA.product_s_desc']', '$row['listaA.product_desc']', '0', '0', '$imagen')");
}while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

With the code above I get a blank screen, and nothing is inserted into the new table. Any ideas?

Comment: `or die;` that will certainly die alright; it'll "kill" it. Do `or die();` but you shouldn't be making it die, get the real errors instead. See the manual on `die()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php - *Plus,* add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` --- ***Do or die,*** I kinda like the sound of that; it's got a nice ring to it, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: I get no error message, I believe the root of the problem is that $row is returning no data. Even if I comment out the insert line (which my code editor is highlighting as a syntax error) and write    echo $row[listaA.product_id] no information is displayed. Is that the correct way to specify the table on the $row?
BTW how do you format code on a comment?

Comment: TBH, I've never done that type of query so I can't help you out there. I suggest you echo/var_dump() what's being passed through it.

Comment: Got an error message with var_dump, if the name of the field only appears in one table (i.e. $row['category_name'] everything is fine, but if the name is repeated across multiple tables (i.e. echo $row['listaA.product_id'] or echo$row['product_id']) I get an undefined index error.

Comment: Don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax, and note that in the absence on an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Just changed the query to order by listaA.product_id and use inner joins, still same error. I'm sure it is something in the $row. How would you specify the table? I mean, the problem is that listaA.product_id is not a field in the query per se, the field is product_id IN the table listaA, I guess this is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query starting...

```
select listaA.product_s_desc, ...
```

returns a resultset, the first column in the resultset will have a column name of `product_s_desc`, not `listaA.product_s_desc`.

(Running the query in the mysql command line client will demonstrate this behavior.)

To reference to the value of that column in `$row`:

```
$row['product_s_desc']
```

Note that the query does not return a column with a name of `listaA.product_id`.

---

A few notes, beyond answering the question you asked:

For the benefit of readers, I recommend you ditch the old school comma syntax for the join operation and use the JOIN keyword in it's place, and relocate the join predicates from the WHERE clause to an ON clause. I also recommend the use of short table aliases, and also qualifying ALL column references. For example:

```
SELECT a.product_s_desc
     , c.category_name
     , a.product_desc
     , a.product_sku
  FROM listaA a
  JOIN jos_vm_product_category_xref r 
    ON r.product_id = a.product_id
  JOIN jos_vm_category c
    ON c.category_id = r.category_id
 ORDER BY 1    
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I totally knew this was the reason it was not working. Thank you for your help